# Esconder f.select a usuarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Me gustaría duplicar el `_form.html` para que muestre diferente opciones a cada persona logueada, por ejemplo una persona pueda ver de un `f.select` 4 opciones de 20 que existen, otra persona pueda ver 3 opciones de las 20.

Como podría crear esto? estoy bastante confundido como hacer esto

```
<% programa = {
 'Cemento/mortero' => 'Cemento/mortero',  'Laminas' => 'Laminas', 'Pintura' =>  'Pintura', 'Tinacos' => 'Tinacos', 'Aspersoras' => 'Aspersoras', 'Calentadores solares' => 'Calentadores solares', 'Baños ecológicos' => 'Baños ecológicos', 'Huertos de traspatio' => 'Huertos de traspatio', 'Mejoramiento de vivienda' => 'Mejoramiento de vivienda', 'Mejoramiento de escuelas' => 'Mejoramiento de escuelas ', 'Calzado escolar' => 'Calzado escolar', 'Ampliación de metas en obra pública y activos fijos.' => 'Ampliación de metas en obra pública y activos fijos.'} %>
<%= f.select :programa,programa, label: "Programa",  control_col: "col-lg-4"%>
```

Comment: Si puedes dar mas detalles de lo que tienes hecho, se podría dar una mejor respuesta. ¿Como es tu tabla de usuarios? ¿que determina si el usuario puede ver una u otras opciones? ¿un atributo? ¿una relación?

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez puedes crear una tabla de nombre programa, con un campo `id` y un campo `nombre`. También una de tipo de usuario que defina que programas puede ver ese usuario. Luego creas otra llamada programas_tipo_usuarios, que sirve de conexión muchos a muchos, con un campo `usuario_id` y `programa_id`.

En el modelo de tipo_usuarios haces la conexión con la de programas:

`has_and_belongs_to_many :programas`

En el modelo de programas haces la conexión con la de tipo de usuarios:

`has_and_belongs_to_many :tipo_usuarios`

En el modelo de usuarios haces la conexión con programas:

`belongs_to :tipo_usuario`
`has_many :programas, through: :tipo_usuarios`

Luego creas en `seed.rb` que programas tenga acceso cada tipo de usuario, luego en la tabla usuario defines con un campo `tipo_usuario_id` a que tipo pertenece.

Finalmente en el form podrás hacer algo como esto:

`<%= f.select :programa, usuario.programas, label: "Programa",  control_col: "col-lg-4"%>`

Comment: No quiero menospreciar tu respuesta, pero creo que esta respuesta es muy muy compleja para lo que OP está pidiendo. En el largo plazo quizá sea esta la opción más escalable, aunque personalmente si tuviera que meter el programa en otro modelo crearía diferentes métodos de clase para obtener subconjuntos del mismo en vez de relacionarlo directamente con el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes muchas formas de hacerlo, yo creo que con la información que das es mejor ir a lo simple por ahora.

Lo que vamos a hacer es mostrar un select u otro en función del usuario mediante un condicional. Voy a tomar tu ejemplo:

```
    <% programa = if condicion_1 
         { 'Calzado escolar' => 'Calzado escolar', 'Ampliación de metas en obra pública y activos fijos.' => 'Ampliación de metas en obra pública y activos fijos.'} 
                  elsif condicion_2   
         { 'Cemento/mortero' => 'Cemento/mortero',  'Laminas' => 'Laminas', 'Pintura' =>  'Pintura'} 
       end %> 

    <%= f.select :programa, programa, label: "Programa",  control_col: "col-lg-4"%>
```

En `condicion_1` y `condicion_2` debes poner las condiciones por las que deseas mostrar uno o otro juego de opciones.

Si ya quieres mejorar tu código un poco más, quizá quieras hacer este control en el controlador y no en la vista, introduciendo el set de opciones en otra variable, dejando tu vista un poco más limpia.

También puedes incluso crear un modelo con las opciones y hacer una query, pero creo que esto ya es complicarse mucho para el ámbito de la pregunta que has hecho. (Si necesitas que amplíe alguna de las opciones por favor indícalo en los comentarios).